# What is the most efficient way to look for a file by name and print its attributes?

Tags: c, filesystems

Sorry if the title isn't very fitting, I have actually multiple question, and I wasn't able to separate them.

I wrote a simplified version of the command line "find" program running on macOS that simply looks for every instance of a file name in a specified path and prints the corresponding file paths if any, and date of last modification. It's a single thread program. I used readdir and lstat to get the necessary file info.

Then I compared the performance of my program, let's call it "myfind"(printing as I said both file path and last modified time), to "find"(used with "find path -name filename", to print only the resulting file paths). "myfind" took 1m 40s and "find" just 40s. Both times were consistent during consecutive tries.

Unhappy about the result, I made some "optimizations" that didn't do anything at all (like removing recursion and using a simple stack holding some variables instead).

This is the code I wrote, error checking removed (executing with or without error checking doesn't change execution time):

```
struct recstruct{
    DIR *st_dir;
    char pathname[512];
};
//usage: ./execname path filename
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    chdir(argv[1]);
    myfind(argv[2]);
    return 0;
}
int myfind(char *name){
    DIR *curr_dir = opendir(".");
    int stk_i = 0;
    struct recstruct stk[128];
    struct dirent *next_entry;
    struct stat info;
    char *entry_name;
    char path[512];
    errno = 0;
    //ignores "." and ".."
    readdir(curr_dir);
    readdir(curr_dir);


    //gets next directory entry until it has fully explored the path
    while((next_entry = readdir(curr_dir)) != NULL || stk_i != 0){
        //goes back to previous directory if there is any and it's done with the current one
        if(next_entry == NULL){
            closedir(curr_dir);
            stk_i--;
            chdir(stk[stk_i].pathname);
            curr_dir = stk[stk_i].st_dir;
            continue;
        }
        //gets next directory entry and checks if its name is the one we are looking for
        entry_name = next_entry->d_name;
        lstat(entry_name, &info);
        if(strncmp(name, entry_name, 127) == 0){
            realpath(entry_name, path);
            printf("path:%s\nlast modified:%s", path, ctime(&(info.st_mtime)));
        }
        //if next_entry is a dir, save current environment and explore the new dir
        if(S_ISDIR(info.st_mode)){ 
            getcwd(stk[stk_i].pathname, 512);
            stk[stk_i].st_dir = curr_dir;
            stk_i++;
            chdir(entry_name);
            curr_dir = opendir(".");
            readdir(curr_dir);
            readdir(curr_dir);
        }
    }
    closedir(curr_dir);
    return 0;
}
```

Then I removed from "myfind" the part where I printed the last modified date by removing all lstat calls. The execution time dropped to 30 seconds, and dropped to about 3-6 seconds on consecutive calls (program calls from terminal, not function calls. The improvement stayed there even after closing and reopening the terminal).

This behavior also improved execution time on consecutive calls that looked for files close in the directory tree, which seems a likely use scenario for this type of program, so I would like to be able to understand it more.

So what I'm actually asking is:

1. How does this improvement on execution time on consecutive calls work exactly? Why isn't it there in neither "find", nor "myfind" when using lstat?
2. Is there any other thing I could change in my code to make it more optimized, while making it also print the last modified date? I'm ok with making it platform dependent, too.

I'm operating on an SSD, and only looking for 1 filename every execution

Comment: Serious walls of text here.

Comment: How many files are there to look at? What kind of device is this operating on, HDD or SDD or network share?

Comment: `name = argv[2]` stomps that allocation you just made and leaks memory. Maybe you mean `strcpy()`? Then again, you can just use that arg as-is. No need to copy it unless you're altering it.

Comment: PSA: Do check `argc` before banging around in `argv`. You may not have the arguments you expect, or in this case, *assume*.

Comment: I fixed the things you pointed out(made that "name" error copying and pasting from different versions of the source code). I removed all error checks including the one on argc for brevity. I know it's a wall of text, sorry for that.

Comment: One thing to note is you do some strange shuffling around to handle directories, when I'd expect to see recursion. You shouldn't have to make your own stack, that's what the call stack is for. Additionally, instead of lots of `chdir()` calls, why not compose paths incrementally in a recursive version and call `opendir` on those directly? These `chdir` calls can really drag things down if there's a lot of directories.

Comment: I should have posted the first version ot the code with recursive calls, seeing this one is equivalent (in both the way it works and performance, unfortunately) but more convoluted. Thanks for the suggestions though

Comment: Stop reading directories yourself and using recursion and change to using `fts_open`, `fts_read`, and `fts_close`. Those are routines designed for traversing a file hierarchy. You just call `fts_open` once and then use `fts_read` to get the next item in the traversal.

Comment: Use strace/ltrace (or similar) on find and see what it does.   Benchmark your program with a profiler gprof (or similar) to find out why your program is slow.

Comment: "Most efficient" is highly context specific.  I never used MacOS so this excludes a bunch of people that could possible help you.  "efficient" and shortest "user" time are no the same thing.

Comment: Use symbolic constants instead of magic numbers... is 512 the max size on MacOS?   Less memory is more faster (pun).  Too little and your program is defective.

Comment: PSA: Don't change your program after you posted it but do edit the question with additional data requested. You should add the missing headers so we know you actually tried to compile this.  Otherwise we are chasing a moving target, and you should assume comments are not read by people trying to help you.

Comment: Your second question is off-topic here. Questions asking for peer review to improve working code belong on [codereview.se], which was created specifically for that purpose. I deconstructed those huge walls of text into readable paragraphs, and broke some very long, run-on sentence structure into shorter sentences that can be read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an implementation using `fts_` as suggested by @EricPostpischil.  It assumes user supplied a directory, if you want to verify that do the first `fts_read()` before the loop and check `fts_info`.  It also assumes that the filename is a basename (doesn't contain any slashes).  You could check that, too.

Look over the options to `fts_open()` to ensure this is the behavior you want.

It's only checking that the filename matches a regular file; `find -name` will also match against directory names.  It's easy to address that just before the `for`-loop.

```
#include <fts.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int myfind(char *const path, const char *filename) {
    FTS *ftsp = fts_open(
        (char *const []) { path, NULL},
        FTS_LOGICAL | FTS_NOCHDIR | FTS_NOSTAT,
        NULL
    );
    if(!ftsp) {
        perror("");
        goto err;
    }
    for(FTSENT *ftsent = fts_read(ftsp); ftsent; ftsent = fts_read(ftsp)) {
        if(ftsent->fts_info & FTS_D)
            for(ftsent = fts_children(ftsp, FTS_NAMEONLY); ftsent; ftsent = ftsent->fts_link)
                if(!strcmp(filename, ftsent->fts_name))
                    printf("%s%s\n", ftsent->fts_path, ftsent->fts_name);
    }
    if(errno) {
        perror("");
        goto err;
    }
    fts_close(ftsp);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
err:
    if(ftsp)
        fts_close(ftsp);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(argc != 3) {
        printf("usage: path filename\n");
        return 0;
    }
    return myfind(argv[1], argv[2]);
}
```

and here are some example runs (with a warm file cache to be comparable):

```
$ time find . -name non-existing_file
real    0m5.296s
user    0m0.865s

$ time ./myfind . non-existing_file
real    0m4.259s
user    0m0.942s
```

```
$ time find  . -name AnsiballZ_file.py
./.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1670391304.3514712-709042-260172808017632/AnsiballZ_file.py
./.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1658890524.6326995-109370-280029288970992/AnsiballZ_file.py
./.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1567991519.7013745-230514371888007/AnsiballZ_file.py
./.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1658888271.8413315-108112-177019459387621/AnsiballZ_file.py

real    0m5.445s
user    0m0.847s
sys     0m0.961s

$ time ./myfind . AnsiballZ_file.py
./.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1670391304.3514712-709042-260172808017632/AnsiballZ_file.py
./.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1658890524.6326995-109370-280029288970992/AnsiballZ_file.py
./.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1567991519.7013745-230514371888007/AnsiballZ_file.py
./.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1658888271.8413315-108112-177019459387621/AnsiballZ_file.py

real    0m7.481s
user    0m0.882s
sys     0m2.713s
```

I see ~3.9 to ~7.6 real time runs on my system so should be comparable to find.